# What should a Traversable instance look like for a Tree datatype with a nested Maybe value?

Tags: haskell, tree, option-type, traversable

I have a Haskell exam in three days, so I thought I should practice a little and pulled up past exams, one of which features the following Tree datatype:

```
data Tree a = Leaf1 a | Leaf2 a a | Node (Tree a) (Maybe (Tree a)) deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

It didn't seem that challenging at first, but then I realized I have to write a Traversable instance for this Tree. Dealing with the leaves were easy enough:

```
instance Traversable Tree where
  traverse f (Leaf1 a)   = Leaf1 <$> f a
  traverse f (Leaf2 a b) = Leaf2 <$> f a <*> f b
```

However, I started running into problems with the Node.

```
  traverse f (Node t Nothing)  = Node <$> traverse f t <*> Nothing
  traverse f (Node l (Just r)) = Node <$> traverse f l <*> Just (traverse f r)
```

Naturally, these don't work, and I can't wrap my head around what should come after the second <*>. I tried using holes, but the messages given to me by ghci didn't help much (I get that the problem is with types, but I have no idea how I'm supposed to fix it).

Here's the error message I got when I tried to compile it:

```
* Couldn't match type `f' with `Maybe'
  `f' is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      traverse :: forall (f :: * -> *) a b.
                  Applicative f =>
                  (a -> f b) -> Tree a -> f (Tree b)
    at exam.hs:92:3-10
  Expected type: f (Maybe (Tree b))
    Actual type: Maybe (Maybe (Tree b))
* In the second argument of `(<*>)', namely `Nothing'
  In the expression: Node <$> traverse f t <*> Nothing
  In an equation for `traverse':
      traverse f (Node t Nothing) = Node <$> traverse f t <*> Nothing
* Relevant bindings include
    f :: a -> f b (bound at exam.hs:94:12)
    traverse :: (a -> f b) -> Tree a -> f (Tree b)
      (bound at exam.hs:92:3)
   |
94 |   traverse f (Node t Nothing)  = Node <$> traverse f t <*> Nothing
   |                                                            ^^^^^^^
```

Could someone please give me some pointers or a possible fix for this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's right (don't have any experience writing Traversable instances for non-trivial data types), but using `pure Nothing` instead of `Nothing` would avoid this type error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`traverse`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:traverse) lets you apply a "function with an effect" to every "slot" of a data structure, maintaining the structure's shape. It has the type:

```
traverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
```

It relies crucially on the fact that the type of the "effects" is an `Applicative`. What operations does `Applicatve` provide?

- it lets us lift pure functions and apply them to effectful actions with `<$>`.
- it lets us combine effectful actions with `(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`. Notice that the second parameter is an effectful action, not a pure value.
- it lets us take any pure value and put it in an effectful context, using `pure :: a -> f a`.

Now, when the node has a `Nothing`, there's no effect to perform because there aren't any values, but the `<*>` still requires an effectful action on the right. We can use `pure Nothing` to make the types fit.

When the node has a `Just t`, we can `traverse` the subtree `t` of type `Tree a` with the function `a -> f b` and end up with an action `f (Tree b)`. But the `<*>` is actually expecting an `f (Maybe (Tree b))`. The lifted `Node` constructor makes us expect that. What can we do?

The solution is to lift the `Just` constructor into the action using `<$>`, which is another name for `fmap`.

Notice that we haven't changed the overall "shape" of the value: the `Nothing` is still `Nothing`, the `Just` is still `Just`. The structure of the subtrees didn't change either: we `traverse`d them recursively but didn't modify them otherwise.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation was easy to follow and thanks to you I got the code to work!

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is that you need to use `traverse` to get inside the `Maybe`.

The `Traversable` and `Foldable` instances for a type often have a similar structure to its `Functor` instance. Whereas `fmap` maps a pure function over a structure, combining the results back up with the pure constructors:

```
instance Functor Tree where
  fmap f (Leaf1 a) = Leaf1 (f a)
  fmap f (Leaf2 a1 a2) = Leaf2 (f a1) (f a2)
  fmap f (Node ta mta) = Node (fmap f ta) (fmap (fmap f) mta)
```

Note the `(fmap (fmap f) mta)`: the outer `fmap` maps over the `Maybe`, while the inner one maps over the `Tree`:

```
(fmap
  :: (Tree a -> Tree b)
  -> Maybe (Tree a) -> Maybe (Tree b))
  ((fmap
    :: (a -> b)
    -> Tree a -> Tree b)
    f)
  mta
```

`traverse` instead maps an effectful function over the structure, and correspondingly lifts the constructors into `Applicative` with the `<$>` and `<*>` operators:

```
instance Traversable Tree where
  traverse f (Leaf1 a) = Leaf1 <$> f a
  traverse f (Leaf2 a1 a2) = Leaf2 <$> f a1 <*> f a2
  traverse f (Node ta mta) = Node <$> traverse f ta <*> traverse (traverse f) mta
```

Again, notice that we must `traverse` the `Maybe`, and within that, `traverse` the `Tree`, but instead of a pure function `a -> b`, we just have an effectful function `a -> f b`, given `Applicative f`:

```
(traverse
  :: (Tree a -> f (Tree b))
  -> Maybe (Tree a) -> f (Maybe (Tree b)))
  ((traverse
    :: (a -> f b)
    -> Tree a -> f (Tree b))
    f)
  mta
```

Likewise, `foldMap` has a similar structure, but instead of reconstructing the data type, it combines results using a `Monoid` instance:

```
instance Foldable Tree where
  foldMap f (Leaf1 a) = f a
  foldMap f (Leaf2 a1 a2) = f a1 <> f a2
  foldMap f (Node ta mta) = foldMap f ta <> foldMap (foldMap f) mta
```

And here’s a simple example usage of `traverse`:

```
> traverse (\ x -> print x *> pure (x + 1)) (Node (Leaf1 10) (Just (Leaf2 20 30)))
10
20
30
Node (Leaf1 11) (Just (Leaf2 21 31))
```

With the `DeriveFoldable`, `DeriveFunctor`, and `DeriveTraversable` extensions, you may add a `deriving (Foldable, Functor, Traversable)` clause to a data type and use the `-ddump-deriv` flag of GHC to see the generated code.